# How to Insert Ads within your Page Content in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, html, adsense

Can you tell me how to insert *Adsense Ads* within your page content in *WordPress* as I've added the code [here](http://share-ask.com).

I don't want manually addition option to each page as its time consuming.

Comment: If you want it on each page, why don't you put it on the header or footer ?

Comment: Dere is already add on the header ,I want inside page content

Comment: What happens if you add it right before the `the_content();` call of your page template ?

Comment: Im using Genesis ao i dont find the_content(); inside  (page.php)

Comment: yeah Genesis is a big stuff, it's kinda harder to find where is the real code... have to move from file to file, for each call to a function until you find the one...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to insert ads is to use one of the plugins:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-publisher/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/adsense-plugin/

Comment: Then you should edit theme template file to display ads for such page.